# Sobre Rotas e Links

Tags: laravel-5

Fiz um crud, porém mudei a organização dos arquivos, em vez de seguir o padrão, criei uma pasta usuario que contém o controller, route e model. Gostaria da ajuda para tentar entender o motivo de não conseguir encontrar a rota pelo link_to_route.

routes.php

```
Route::resource('/', '\App\Usuario\Http\Controllers\UsuariosController');
```

usuarios/index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{$usuario->nome}}</td>
        <td>{{$usuario->sobrenome}}</td>
        <td>{{$usuario->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$usuario->usuario}}</td>
        <td>{{$usuario->created_at}}</td>
        <td>{{$usuario->updated_at}}</td>
        <!--É necessário uma rotas nomeada-->
        <td>{{ link_to_route('edit', $title = 'Editar', $usuario->id, $attributes = []) }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
@endforeach
```

Este é o erro:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente gostaria de agradecer ao Evert e Vinicius Luiz.

A solução que encontrei foi a seguinte:

Como dentro da view estava com outro diretório no qual chamei de Usuarios > Index.blade.php

O link_to_route modifiquei colocando o nome da view + index para:

```
<td>{{ link_to_route('usuarios.edit', $title = 'Editar', $usuario->id) }}</td>
```

As rotas continuaram dessa forma:

```
Route::resource('usuarios', '\App\Usuario\Http\Controllers\UsuariosController');
```

Comment: Você também pode opcionalmente configurar o namespace base dos controllers através do `RouteServiceProvider`

Answer (score 1):

Tente alterar para:

```
Route::get('/' , 'UsuariosController@metodoDoControllerUtilizado');
```

Isto deve funcionar para o seu caso

Comment: Obrigado Vinicius Luiz por ter disponibilizado um tempo para me ajudar.

Comment: De acordo com a solução que você comentou abaixo dá para refazê-la de um jeito mais simples...

Answer (score 1):

Na sua view ficará mais ou menos algo assim:

```
<td>{{ route('usuarios.edit' , [$title => 'Editar' , 'ID_USUARIO' => $usuario->id]) }}</td>
```

E sua rota será a seguinte:

```
Route::get('usuarios' , ['as' => 'usuarios.edit' , 'UsuariosController@METODO']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie a estrutura que deseja, atualize seu *namespace*, retire o caminho e deixe apenas:

```
Route::resource('/', 'UsuariosController');
```

É necessário que seu *controller* se estenda à classe *Controller*.

Faça um:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Tente novamente e veja se funciona.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Evert por ter disponibilizado um tempo para me ajudar.